# Посоветуй хороший IDE для разработки бекенда parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, ide

Посоветуй хорошeую IDE для разработки бекенда parse cloud code на JavaScript. Ранее никогда не писал на JavaScript. Надо хорошую IDE, чтобы показывала подсказки.

Comment: Наверное, вам нужна IDE, а не IDEA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте кросплатформенную [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). В ней есть подсветка синтаксиса и подсказки для `Javascript`, `html`, `css` и прочих веб-технологий и языков. Благодаря встроенному веб-серверу `node.js` очень легко проверять работу написанного кода.

Другие продукты [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/) также включают в себя эту функциональность, то там есть и много лишнего в вашем случае.

Если вы работаете с Windows, то можно попробовать оценить мощь [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/). Например, у нее есть бесплатная редакция Community. Так же есть встроенный веб-сервер IIS Express, подсветка кода и подсказки. Совместно с [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) вообще здорово.

Недавно появилась среда разработки [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) от Майкрософт. Она кросплатформенная, но ее возможности пока немного ограничены.

Веб-среды разработки Javascript достаточно удобны для небольших задач, но имеют ограниченный функционал для обучающихся. К таким можно отнести [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: А почему не упомянули о том, что WebStorm (как и все продукты JetBrains) -- платная? :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev У JetBrains не все продукты платные и для каждого продукта есть бесплатные лицензии. А так да, спасибо за замечание.

Answer (score 0):

Я в полседнее время подсел на Brackets. всё есть и бесплатно + куча расширений на любой вкус и цвет